# How to create custom commands to perform crud operations in magento 2

Tags: magento2, crud

How to create custom commands to perform crud operations in Magento 2.I am not getting help online. please provide code if possible.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I wanted to create a custom console command to perform crud operation. without using a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the following Steps:

1. Create a file Abc.php in Vendor/Module/Console/Command folder.

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Jasvir\Test\Console\Command;
>
> use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
> use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
> use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
> use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
> use Jasvir\Test\Model\ItemFactory;
> use Magento\Framework\Console\Cli;
> class AddItem extends Command
>
> {
> ```

```
    const INPUT_KEY_NAME = 'name';
    const INPUT_KEY_DESCRIPTION = 'description';
    const INPUT_KEY_COMMENT = 'comments';
    private $itemFactory;

    public function __construct(ItemFactory $itemFactory)
    {
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('mastering:add:item')
            ->addArgument(
                self::INPUT_KEY_NAME,
                InputArgument::REQUIRED,
                'Item Name'
            )
            ->addArgument(
                self::INPUT_KEY_DESCRIPTION,
                InputArgument::OPTIONAL,
                'Item Description'
            )
            ->addArgument(
                self::INPUT_KEY_COMMENT,
                InputArgument::OPTIONAL,
                'Item Comments'
            );         
        parent::configure();
    }

    /**
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     *
     * @return null|int
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $item = $this->itemFactory->create();
        $item->setName($input->getArgument(self::INPUT_KEY_NAME));
        $item->setDescription($input->getArgument(self::INPUT_KEY_DESCRIPTION));
        $item->setComments($input->getArgument(self::INPUT_KEY_COMMENT));
        $item->setIsObjectNew(true);
        $item->save();
        return Cli::RETURN_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Then in command line run the following command:

php bin/magento mastering:add:item  "Magento 2 "  "It is a CMS" "Comment"

There is some other things you have to consider before this.

Please refer to this video. I followed this whole video and learn a great deal from this.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZZtebIv_Ws

Comment: Class "Techsevin\HelloTechsevin\Console\Add\Interceptor" does not exist, I am facing this error, after trying your code.

Comment: Thank you bro,After some changes it is working fine.